# Improve proficiency in programming

Tags: c#, language-agnostic

How can I increase my proficiency in programming? I have a grasp of the basics of C#, but don't feel too confident about my ability.

Comment: You're welcome Beth.. I mean, unknown :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Code something in C#
- Read C# Code and try to understand it.
- Read a C# Book (and please none of the C# in 21 Days books)

**The confidence comes with the experience.**

Comment: That is about it.  A VERY good book is the one by Andrew Troelsen.

Comment: Whats your preferred book? (or website resource)

Comment: What the name of the book you mentioned? Still waiting for jon to finish his :)

Comment: Martin, would you like to share which of Andrews book you are referring?

Comment: Maybe you should put your last sentence, about confidence, first and bold.

Comment: Pro C# 2008 and the .NET 3.5 Platform, Fourth Edition

Answer (score 9):

Read Stack Overflow every day :)

Seriously. Try to solve interesting problems. Even if you don't post your solution, come back later and see if other people came up with something similar, why their solution might be different, etc.

Comment: Great idea Thorain. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8):

[Project Euler](http://projecteuler.net).

Answer (score 4):

http://www.asp.net/LEARN/videos/

Voile, you are programing ASP.net.

Keep in mind that you may need a little more grasp on C# as your codes evolve. For that use a good book, most Microsoft's learn C# are pretty neat(The learn ASP.net is quite lame).
Of course, thats what I did back then(about 2 years ago), nowadays you should be able to find some awesome tutorials online.
Good luck ;)

Answer (score 4):

Think of a fun project of some complexity (more that "Hello, world") and code it.

Practice, practice, practice!

Also read forums, blogs, participate in discussions. You will learn many things that aren't even mentioned in books.

Answer (score 3):

read lots of code, write lots of code and keep a copy of [C# 3.0 in a nutshell](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596527578) handy.

Answer (score 3):

Learn new programming languages.  Learn data structures and algorithms and design patterns.  Learn regular expressions.  Learn databases.  Learn HTML/XHTML/DOM.  Learn learn learn learn learn.

In programming, knowledge === power.

Answer (score 2):

Work on something, even if it's reinventing the wheel. You can read books, watch videos and listen to podcasts all day, but the real experience comes from actually building an application. Don't build an application that you know you can build - instead, create an application that is slightly out of your reach, then rinse and repeat.

The experience when you realize that you created a mess of spaghetti code that is unmaintainable cannot really be substituted, as this then really allows you to look into techniques to improve your code. Sure, feel free to read on MSDN about Events, Delegates and Lambdas, but reading about them in the moment you need them means that the knowledge really burns into your memory.

I try to have a rough knowledge about as many topics as possible, but that's usually rather shallow: I know that a technique exists and roughly what problem it solves, so that when I need it I can learn about it.

In my opinion, the only alternative to first-hand real world experience is even more first-hand real world experience.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.appdev.com/csharp.asp

:)

Comment: AppDev SUCKS!!! (and is mucho expensive)

Comment: i dont think it sucks but its expensive thats true

Comment: There are too many free resources to both with appdev. If there is a specific need, that it could be considered but in the context of this question, it doesn't quite fit (There are better solutions)

Answer (score 1):

You say you are learning ASP.NET and C#. Have you ever done any programming or web development? Because, if you have not, then you need to take a step back and learn the basics of HTML, CSS and get a grasp of how data is passed via HTTP between client and server. I would also strongly advise getting a grounding in basic SQL, because most serious web development will utilise databases at some point.

After that, some basic OOP (Object-orientated programming) theory would do you good. That way you have a good grounding in the subject-matter before diving into the coding.

For learning C# the I'd suggest a couple of good tutorials:

[The C# Station Tutorial](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorials/Lesson01.aspx) and [Softsteel Solutions C# tutorial](http://www.softsteel.co.uk/tutorials/cSharp/contents.html).

I also found the [ASP.NET Quickstarts](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartV20/aspnet/) useful when I was learning ASP.NET - I prefer to learn by example than by theory.

As for confidence, I'm afraid that only comes via experience. Perhaps try answering a few questions here? Getting a few up-votes might just give you that boost. Good luck.

Comment: Dan, I have vb experience & vb.net experience. But companies these days like C#. So I need to gain confidence in the curly brackets and semicolons;

Answer (score 1):

This fits in to catagory of answers you've received thus far, but **review open source projects.**

Understand how they work and maybe even why they were put together in a given way. Not only will it improve your ability to write C# but it will also improve your understanding of **Software Engineering** which is ultimately how you put a programming language -- C# or otherwise -- to good use.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a Project that makes use of a lot of different technologies is a good way to grasp a 'big picture' view.

As an example, think of an n-tier application where you input a value into a very simple web page, this value being sent into a web service, and behind that WS a simple business layer that switches between readings into a table of a data base, then you return the value finishing the output in a postback of the initial web page. In my Personal opinion, every element of the layer is a simple one, but, making the whole system work without errors is good beginner's challenge, that way you could build a confidence in your skills, enabling you to undertake any other idea.

Well, that were my two cents. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

There may be so many projects that u can make.choose the project that makes u.it's true take a project that you consider difficult for your level.
1) analyse your project
2) define the objective 
   find things that are necessary to achieve the objective
3)then derive an algorithm which clearly explains the workflow
4)then start woking

In my experience "***Learn By Working***" is a good idea.first grab the basics then start the work soon you'll learn step by step.never give up ,be a ceaseless crusader.
practise practise it's a only way of surviving as a programmer.

Being a best programmer requires a lot of patience,thinking skills,Attention,a thrist for knowledge.

Wise people always replace the fear of unkonwn with curiosity

Comment: Hi first of all  saw your post accidentally It's nice really giving clarity byt i'd like disagree on "Learn by working".bcua it is not good mechanism after all.I think the better way is first learn the text box then you can enhance your skills by working bcuz without having the clearer ideas and start working on somthing eventually takes away lots of time and it's not as effecient as book first approach....I am telling this because i have done and seen other's been doing...

Answer (score 0):

Actively participate in programming (and non-programming) forums.